# Consume MS Graph API in Azure Active Directory : C# and Postman

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am new to MS Graph API and was trying to retrieve the SharePoint List Items using MS Graph registered in Azure AD . I was able to retrieve the access token by passing the following parameters(client_id,client_secret,resource,authority) so the problem lies while running the api url : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{site-id}}/lists/{{list-id}}/items?$Select=Id&$expand=fields($select=Title)` in Postman (by passing Bearer-access token in Header).

I received the following error stating that "**Either scp or role claim need to be present in the token**".It would be great if you could guide me to provide the right solution since I am trying to consume the api using C# and was receiving the following error stating that "**403-Forbidden**"

```html
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{site-id}}/lists");
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;


//var result = requestTask.Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  var readTask = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  readTask.Wait();
  Console.WriteLine("Response:" + readTask);
}

}
```

Comment: And if you still  have problem, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the collection of items in a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), you need have the following permission.

[image]

And according to the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wryfl.png) you provided, the application permission of `Sites.Read.All` and `Sites.ReadWrite.All` do not grant consent, so it shows the yellow warnings. The right status is as below:

[image]

You need to grant admin consent to these permission, and then decoded the access token you will see the app permission in `role` claim.

[image]